# I Have a variable issue that i cant figure out

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import webbrowser
import time
# First Update DATE: 11/28/2018
# Created by hassan alaa: Version 2.0

print("Tab Timer Version 2.0 *UPDATE*")

while True:
    stuff = input("Hey Welcome What Are You Using This For Work, School Or Personal?: ")
    if stuff == "work":
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Authorizing...")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Authorized! Have Fun")
    if stuff == "school":
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Authorizing...")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Authorized! Have Fun!")
    if stuff == "personal":
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Authorizing...")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Authorized! Have Fun!")
    if stuff == "ANONYMOUS04":
        username = input("What Is The Username?: ")
        password = input("What Is The Password?: ")
    if username == "M8TE" and password == "CICADA3007":
        print("Welcome Dear Master Hassan!")
    else:
        print("You Ugly Fool, You Aren't Master!")
        time.sleep(2)
```

there is an issue because username is not defined but i did define it!

Comment: you only define username `if stuff == "ANONYMOUS04":`

Comment: So how do i fix it?

Comment: @Yeahpygod define username when it is not `ANONYMOUS04` also

Comment: How can show me the code that would be incredible

Comment: put `username = ''` after the definition of `stuff` and `password`

Comment: put username at the top. This is a scoping issue. username is not defined at the same scope as the block with username == 'M8TE'. Once you've defined username then you can re-define twitch the input('... stuff' that you have there

Comment: Man you guys are amazing thank so much im so glad for you guys!

Comment: Increase indent of the last 5 lines with 4 spaces.

Comment: Actually i have more code at the bottom soooo.

Comment: `if stuff in ( "work", "school", 'personal'): # do the sleepy printing stuff ` would shorten this remarkably - also use elif , it makes the resulting code better

Answer (score 0):

No, your `username` variable is not defined, since it has wrong indentation. Maybe you want this:

```
    if stuff == "ANONYMOUS04":
        username = input("What Is The Username?: ")
        password = input("What Is The Password?: ")
        if username == "M8TE" and password == "CICADA3007":
            print("Welcome Dear Master Hassan!")
```

in this case it is defined since it is at the same indentation level it was defined.